# How to solve error during deploy ionic app in emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, deployment, android-emulator

I want to deploy my ionic app on emulator. The following are the version of application I'm using to do it.

Ionic:
3.20.1

Cordova :
8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

Android :
7.1.1

When I run the **ionic cordova emulate android** command on Powershell. The following error I got.

```
Waiting for emulator to start...

emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start

emulator: Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
emulator: WARNING: cannot read adb public key file: C:\Users\Utkarsh 
Soni\.android\adbkey.pub
emulator: WARNING: trying again by copying from home dir
emulator: WARNING: cannot read adb public key file (failed): C:\Users\Utkarsh 
Soni\.android\adbkey.pub
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: 
C:\Users\Utkarsh Soni\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: 
Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: device still authorizing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:

Create new virtual device.

Step 2:

Choose device which is **not** google play store.

Step 3:

In advance settings: Graphics should be hardware.

Done.